# function not call on the right html tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function like that

```
function get_file_size()
{
    $size = '';
        if (get_field('size') && get_field('megabyte')) :
            $size = the_field('size');
            the_field('megabyte');
        endif;
    return $size;  //it return 20mb
}
```

my problem comes when I want to call the above function in theme.

```
        $size_link = get_file_size();
        $output = sprintf(
            '<span class="%1$s">%2$s</span>',
            esc_attr(join(' ', $classes)),
            $size_link
        );
```

the above code return

```
20mb20mb
<span></span>
```

by the way, when I try to like this

```
    $output = sprintf(
        '<span class="%1$s">%2$s</span>',
        esc_attr(join(' ', $classes)),
       get_file_size()
    );
```

nothing print!

Comment: Can you dump `$output` and say what it contains? What you claim it returns is likely just the browser trying to make sense of invalid HTML. _Not_ what `$output` actually contained.

Comment: @Ivar var dump: " 600MBstring(57) ". I want to print it like this "<span>600MB</span>

Comment: `the_field('megabyte');` will output that value straight away, so your function returns something _and_ outputs something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `the_field` in your `get_file_size` method prints the value, change these to `get_field` instead.